# sep argument in paste0() function behaves not as expected

Tags: r, string, paste

I want to paste characters and separate them with certain sign, a `,` for example. Using `paste()` function works as expected:

```
paste("1st", "2nd", "3rd", sep = ", ")
[1] "1st, 2nd, 3rd"
```

But using the `paste0()` function results in a character with the separator only at the end:

```
paste0("1st", "2nd", "3rd", sep = ", ")
[1] "1st2nd3rd, "
```

I thought the main difference between both functions is that `paste()` makes a space by default and since I specified `sep` to be "`, "` in both examples I expect the same result. But this is not the case. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: paste0 doesn't have a `sep` argument.  So, if you add the `", "`, it will be taken as the 4th element because of variadkc `...`

Comment: @akrun Oh yes, now I see it in the documentary. Missed it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paste0` function does not have a `sep=` parameter. It was specifically created to not use a separator. So these are all the same

```
paste0("1st", "2nd", "3rd", sep=", ")
paste0("1st", "2nd", "3rd",  ", ")
paste0(a="1st", b="2nd", c="3rd",  d=", ")
```

Check the `?paste0` help page for more info. If you want a separator, don't use `paste0`. This is expected bahavior.